# My "href" links get added to the end of the root URL

Tags: html, css

Whenever I try to change what a link(Image, Text, etc.) will route to, it always gets added to the end of the root URL.

Example:

```
<a href="google.com"> will link to root.url\google.com
(root.url is not the actual domain name)
```

HTML:

```
 <header class="header">
        <div class="header-inner">
            {{search_in_category}}
        <div class="logo"><a href="google.com"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.logo a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 130px;
 }
.logo img {
  max-height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any particular reason why it would be doing this?

Comment: You need to specify http:// otherwise it will resolve to the current domain.

Comment: Any kind of `href`/`src` must be fully-qualified (protocol and all) if you want a destination outside of your current domain.

Comment: For what it's worth, your HTML (other than the first hyperlink) and CSS is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Wow... I feel dumb. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `http://` or `https://` before domain in `href` attribute.

```
<a href="https://google.com">Link text</a>
```

You can also use **protocol-relative** URLs whenever you feel is appropriate. These will be automatically interpreted as using the same protocol that is currently used to view the page.

```
<a href="//example.com/sample.jpg">Link text</a>
```

(This is most useful when linking to third-party resources available over both `http://` and `https://` protocols.)